# Plot colour image from a numpy array that has 3 channels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

in my Jupyter notebook I am trying to display an image that I am iterating on through Keras. The code I am using is as below

```
def plotImages(path, num):
 batchGenerator = file_utils.fileBatchGenerator(path+"train/", num)
 imgs,labels = next(batchGenerator)
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(224, 224))
 plt.gray()
 for i in range(num):
    sub = fig.add_subplot(num, 1, i + 1)
    sub.imshow(imgs[i,0], interpolation='nearest')
```

But this only plots single channel, so my image is grayscale. How do I use the 3 channels to output a colour image plot. ?

Comment: What is the shape of `imgs`?

Comment: 224*224*3, in the above code I am printing channel 1

Comment: So just do `sub.imshow(imgs)` to use all channels. How do you expect it to show RGB if you don't provide all channels?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to display an RGB image, you have to supply *all three channels*. Based on your code, you are instead displaying just the first channel so `matplotlib` has no information to display it as RGB. Instead it will map the values to the `gray` colormap since you've called `plt.gray()`

Instead, you'll want to pass all channels of the RGB image to `imshow` and then the true color display is used and the colormap of the figure is disregarded

```
sub.imshow(imgs, interpolation='nearest')
```

**Update**

Since `imgs` is actually `2 x 3 x 224 x 224`, you'll want to index into `imgs` and permute the dimensions to be `224 x 224 x 3` prior to displaying the image

```
im2display = imgs[1].transpose((1,2,0))
sub.imshow(im2display, interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: I am getting an error , 'TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data'

Comment: @Abhik You said your image was `244 x 244 x 3`. What does `imgs.shape` show?

Comment: (2, 3, 224, 224) - 2 images of 3 *224*224 . Hence I am doing sub.imshow(imgs[i], interpolation='nearest') , where i is the index of the image .

Comment: `TypeError: transpose() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple), but expected one of:
 * (int dim0, int dim1)
 * (name dim0, name dim1)`

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you:
Try putting the channels last by permitting,

```
image.permute(2 , 3 , 1 , 0)
```

and then remove the image index by np.squeeze():

```
plt.imshow((np.squeeze(image.permute(2 , 3 , 1 , 0))))
```